# Prestashop : assets files and css do not load anymore

Tags: css, prestashop, assets

I am having a problem with my prestashop site.
Since this morning the `css` file does not load anymore. After looking into the server it seams that it does not load all files after `/assets` 
Does anyone know where the problem is and how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you refresh your cache (Advanced parameters > Performance > Clear cache)
And also check the permissions on the following folders: var/cache/dev and var/cache/prod

Comment: yes I already did all that... it does not sold the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the console tab of browser's dev tools, there might be JS errors there.